# Geocoder does not work for certain addresses

Tags: android, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am using the goecoder to try to convert address to lat/lng. However, it seems the geocoder works for some addresses but not others. If I search the address on google maps then it pinpoint it perfectly.

Here is an example 38 Crichton Street, Ottawa, ON, Canada
This address returns 0 results when I run the code below

```
            Location loc = null;
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {

                List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(addr, 1);
                if (address.size() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                double latitude = address.get(0).getLatitude();
                double longitude = address.get(0).getLongitude();
                loc = new Location("Unknown");
                loc.setLatitude(latitude);
                loc.setLongitude(longitude);
            }  catch (IOException ioException) {
                Log.e(TAG, ioException.toString());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
                Log.e(TAG, illegalArgumentException.toString());
            }
```

Any idea why or how I can fix it

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why native Android API geocoder cannot find this address. I can see that this address is found in Geocoding API web service:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=38%20Crichton%20Street%2C%20Ottawa%2C%20ON%2C%20Canada&key=MY_API_KEY`

You can also see it in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D38%2520Crichton%2520Street%252C%2520Ottawa%252C%2520ON%252C%2520Canada

As a workaround you can consider using the Geocoding API web service. Please note that there is a Java client library for web services that you can find on Github:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

The Javadoc for client library is located at

https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.2.5/javadoc/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I found the reason. Apperently, if you dont include the province and country then even the web api Geocoder does not find it However, if you put the full address including province and country then the webapi finds it. So Unfortunelty Geocoder is a no go either way